Trouble understanding how to maintain API data state between components
I am having an issue where, if I load my page for the first time things work perfectly fine. However when I try to navigate to another page, my api data is just completely lost.
Here is my tree:
App - Homepage
Pokemon - PokemonCard <--- Here is where I think my issue is. The data is passed as a prop from the Pokemon component to the PokemonCard component
So for additional context, I am making an API call in a page, then passing that api data to the rendered child component. However the data seems to be lost in the process.
Here is the code for my pokemon page. Please let me know if youd like to see other code snippets.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from 'axios'

function PokemonPage() {

    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();
    const { currentPokemon } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("PokemonPage Mounted")
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      const getPokeDetails = async () => {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${currentPokemon}`
          );
          console.log(`API Data for ${currentPokemon} Loaded`)
          setPokemon(response.data);
        // const firstFourMoves = results.moves.slice(0,4).map(move => move.move.name);
        // setMoves(firstFourMoves)
      };

      getPokeDetails();
    }, [currentPokemon]);


    return (
    <>
        <h2>{currentPokemon}</h2>
        <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon}/>
    </>
    )
}
export default PokemonPage;


"Seems to be lost"?  Do you see the console.log message?  Have you tried logging the response data to see if it really looks like you expect?

Add pokemon to your useEffect dependency array, https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#examples-dependencies

@TimRoberts Yes, I am console logging and the data works fine at first

@clxrity that seems to create an infinity loop when I do that

If you need to manage state across components I would urge you to use context instead of passing props. You can set the state in a global variable and as long as you don't refresh the page or dom your variable will remain constant.
If you are requiring data from an API storing context is the better method in my opinion. If you are storing a variable that doesn't need to be fetched then localstorage works as well.

Create a new jsx file called PokemonContext.jsx



import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
const UserContext = createContext();

export default function PokemonContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentPokemon, setCurrentPokemon] = useState("pikachu");

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentPokemon,
        setCurrentPokemon,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const PokemonValues = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};




Wrap your App with the context provider:



 <PokemonContextProvider>
    <App />
 </PokemonContextProvider>




Now you can import the state into your variable:



import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";
import { PokemonValues } from "../AuthContext";

function PokemonPage() {
  const { currentPokemon } = PokemonValues();

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("PokemonPage Mounted");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPokeDetails = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${currentPokemon}`
      );
      console.log(`API Data for ${currentPokemon} Loaded`);
      setPokemon(response.data);
      // const firstFourMoves = results.moves.slice(0,4).map(move => move.move.name);
      // setMoves(firstFourMoves)
    };

    getPokeDetails();
  }, [currentPokemon]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{currentPokemon}</h2>
      <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} />
    </>
  );
}
export default PokemonPage;




Now set your currentpokemon instead of running it as a parameter.


This seems like a solid answer. I will def give it a try. I havent used context like this. Ive only ever used useOutletContext()

Context is awesome for global states. Let me know if you need anymore info on this. It can be a little tricky to set up at first but once you do its a huge life saver for a lot of react issues


First of all, I recommand to setup the pokemon state to null at first,
**const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(null);**


and check if the data is fetched before sending it to the Other Component  :
{pokemon ? < PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} /> : Loading...}

if you can provide the Pockemoncard component and the main.js component will be great.
console.log("Goodbye, Hope you find the solution asap!");


